# long division in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to divide a long(someValue) by a int. That must return a decimal value.
I tried,

```
double result =  (double)(someValue/3600);

double result =  (double)((double)someValue/(double)3600);
```

but to no avail. The result I get is a  whole number.
Please help.

Comment: What are your expectations? What are you actual results? Give us examples.

Comment: `(double)someValue/3600` or `someValue/3600.0` is sufficient to "promote everything" to double/double, if `someValue` is not already a double. Anyway, what "doesn't work" to "no avail"?

Comment: "precise value" may not be possible in either binary or decimal. What would you expect if, say the long were 10 and the int were 3?

Comment: I have just one problem.
You ask for a precise value and you use Double?

Double is saved as floating point what means you will not always have precise results.  Are you aware of that?

Comment: Sorry for incomplete question. But the result of the division is not in decimal.

Comment: @Swamy: As far as Java is concerned, it is. What is it that makes you think it isn't?

Comment: The result of the division is a `double`. What do you mean "not in decimal"? It can certainly be printed in decimal. Please provide more detail about what you're trying to accomplish, what exactly is not working, and what code you are using. (In particular, code that **demonstrates** the problem.)

Comment: So use the right type ;). [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close because we still haven't gotten relevant information about OP's expectations.

Comment: A _whole number_ doesn't mean anything. How are you printing it? What are you doing with the `result` variable? Give us an example of `someValue`'s value. Give us what you think `result` should have as a value.

Comment: How can six people possibly provide an answer to a question, without having any idea what it means?  I'm contemplating downvoting all six.

Comment: @DavidWallace What would you do for a Klondike bar?

Comment: Well, we don't have them where I live, so I guess I'd have to go on an aeroplane for a klondike bar :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. This wont work because you are calculating the result and then do the cast.

   ```
   double result =  (double)(someValue/3600);
   ```
2. But why didnt this work? For me it works fine, because you cast the values to double before calculating.

   ```
   double result =  (double)((double)someValue/(double)3600);
   ```

But there is no need for casting the result again! Or for casting both values to double. And its enough if you add an `d` to the end of the number to tell the compiler that this number should be a dobule value:

```
double result = someValue/3600d;
```

Comment: The first answer that *acknowledges* the OPs code "should work" - +1.

Comment: @user2864740 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167832/is-works-fine-here-an-answer

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Let me put another way: unlike *other* answers, this answer acknowledges that the OPs code *already is* double/double in the 2nd case. Other answers *incorrectly* make claims that extra parenthesis are required or somehow affect the behavior.

Comment: I prefer `double result = someValue / 3600.0;`

Comment: Added d at the end of the number. Worked! But don't why the 2 option is not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you need precise floating point calculations, the recommended way to do it is to use `BigDecimal`.  That is the truly platform-independent way to go (any other one will get you architecture-dependent results).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

This is quite a nice tutorial on `BigDecimals` and their usage

http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/How_to_Use_Java_BigDecimal:_A_Tutorial

Answer (score 1):

```
double result =  (double)(someValue/3600);
```

This won't work because `someValue/3600` will be calculated first, and it'll be made with `int` calculations.

You should *explicitly* cast one side (the other will be cast *implicitly*):

```
double result = (double)someValue/3600;
```

Comment: Why won't the 2nd case work?

Comment: If `someValue` is a `long`, then the result will be a `long` casted to a `double`.

Comment: OP already shows an "equivalent" in the 2nd case, yet claims "no avail".

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis **if** is not enough. OP didn't say anything about it. From what's he trying to do, I guess it's a `double`.

Comment: But you're right, maybe we should wait for further information from OP.

Comment: If `someValue` is a `double`, then there is no issue.

Comment: Sorry, I think my answer is valid.

Comment: It mostly is, which is why I upvoted. But `Then you're casting the int result to double` is wrong if we assume that `I am trying to divide a long by a int.`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You're right, I missed that `long`.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun Whoops, I incorrectly commented and downvoted here. I've removed my downvote, but the other "correct" answer is still wrong.

Comment: @user2864740 Downvotes are more than welcome when they're explained. OP's question is very misleading.. I'm waiting for his clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have at least one of them as `double`. You're typecasting the result of the division as `double` instead. This piece of code will make it:

```
double result = ((double)someValue)/((double)3600);
```

Just in case some people don't trust about code above, refer to [this example](http://ideone.com/4rfhOa).

---

Another solution will be using 3600.0 instead:

```
double result = someValue/3600.0;
```

Comment: OP already shows an "equivalent" in the 2nd case, yet claims "no avail".

Comment: @user2864740 it is not the same since OP casts the result of the whole division while my example casts **each** variable.

Comment: Refer to `(double)((double)someValue/(double)3600);` from the OP. Note that the result of `(double)1/4` is (double) `0.25` - the cast has higher precedence.

Comment: @user2864740 **check** the parenthesis usage...

Comment: Please see above. 1) The `(double)x/y` - cast has *higher precedence*, you parenthesis are superfluous, 2) `x/(double)3600`, the original code is already double/double

Comment: **That's a valid answer**, +1.

Comment: @user2864740 read again: `((double)someValue)`...

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun It is not. The `(double)someValue/(double)3600` **as per the post** is equivalent.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That is misleading and it does not matter.  (double)1/4 == 0.25` while `(double)(1/4) == 0`.

Comment: @user2864740 looks like you need to test the code before upvoting/downvoting. I've created a test for people that don't trust in the first answer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I've just tested it. You can see for yourself. http://ideone.com/HNrLLI - As you can see *casting has higher precedence*.,

Comment: @user2864740 then the problem is not in my answer nor in other people answers, but from OP for doesn't explain what's looking for...

Comment: This answer is *wrong/misleading* because it *presumes* that the extra parenthesis are required. They are not and the code is *equivalent* to the OPs 2nd case.

Comment: @user2864740 just provided another way to solve it. Seriously, if my code prints a decimal, it is not misleading, is just another way to solve it. The main problem here is to find OP's specific problem (and nor you with your comments and downvotes are helping to find about it).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza This answer *ignores* the fact that it is equivalent. You've said something but said nothing relevant given the 2nd example. Nor have you given any indication that the 2nd case *would/should* "work".

Comment: @user2864740 as the other answers do?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I've only voted for one answer here - the one that addresses (as opposed to ignores) the 2nd expression given by the OP. (I still believe the OP has to make a case for a "real problem".)

Answer (score 0):

Things to be aware when doing floating point arithematic:

You frist way, `someValue/3600` is going to be calculated first, and that's a integer division, and it will give you an integer, and then casted to a double, which doesn't give you a correct answer.

You should have both of the value being a double.  Therefore your second way *should work*.  Just a bit of extra information here: you don't really need to cast both number to double.  During a division, if the compiler found that one of the value is an integer and the other is a double, the integer will be promoted to be a double for calculation, giving you the same result.

You may sometime find the result "inaccurate" even you are using second way.  This is because floating point number is only a binary approximation which cannot present all decimal value accurately.  You may consider using BigDecimal if you want an "accurate" decimal value, or learn to deal with floating point number properly.